# Install an older package through macports

Tags: macports

I am trying

```
sudo port install opencv @2.4.3_1+python27
```

but macports installs opencv @2.4.6.1_0+python27

how can I force macports to install the desired version of a package.

Comment: Maybe you'll take a look here -> https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/InstallingOlderPort , http://guide.macports.org/chunked/using.html

Comment: @TheMiniJohn thank you. if you had written you comment as an answer i could have accepted it ;)