# Install older cmake version with macports

Tags: cmake, macports

Is there a way to downgrade `cmake` with `macports`? I can see only one version on the macports site and I need to go back to version 2.8

Answer (score 0):

See

- [Install an older package through macports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831402/install-an-older-package-through-macports)
- [How to downgrade macports software to old revision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242834/how-to-downgrade-macports-software-to-old-revision)
- [Downgrade Python from version 2.7.9 to 2.7.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815620/downgrade-python-from-version-2-7-9-to-2-7-8/27816636#27816636)

all of which point to

- https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/InstallingOlderPort